# Function runs repeat automatically android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a ecommerce app that add data to firestore and on another activity it get all data and show but the problem is that method (for adding data) is running asynchronies some time it runs two time some time it runs 4 time and inside the data base in some collection there is lots of data an in some few data but i need only one. I don't know what can I do now. Please help
code :-

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            boolean isDocPresent = false;

            if (value != null && !value.getDocuments().isEmpty()){
                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = value.getDocuments();
                for (int i = 0; i < snapshots.size(); i++){
                    String catName = snapshots.get(i).getString(Statics.CATEGORY_FIELD_IN_FIRESTORE);
                    if (catName.equals(categoryReceive)){
                        Log.d("LOG",  "Category find");
                        isDocPresent = true;

                        String catId = snapshots.get(i).getString(Statics.CATEGORY_ID_FIRESTORE);

                        DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
                                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                .document(catId)
                                .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                .document();
                        String id = documentReference.getId();

                        Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                        map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_ID_FIRESTORE, productId);
                        map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_DOCUMENT_ID_FIRESTORE, id);

                        documentReference.set(map1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    startActivity(new Intent(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, "Some problem occurs we add this product soon automatically", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!isDocPresent){
                    Log.d("LOG",  "Category not find");
                    DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
                            .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                            .document();
                    String docId = documentReference.getId();

                    Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                    map1.put(Statics.CATEGORY_FIELD_IN_FIRESTORE, categoryReceive);
                    map1.put(Statics.CATEGORY_ID_FIRESTORE, docId);

                    documentReference.set(map1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
                                        .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                        .document(docId)
                                        .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                        .document();
                                String id = documentReference.getId();

                                Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                                map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_ID_FIRESTORE, productId);
                                map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_DOCUMENT_ID_FIRESTORE, id);

                                documentReference.set(map1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        startActivity(new Intent(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                            
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, "Some problem occurs we add this product soon automatically", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
                                });
                            } else {
                               
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            else {
                Log.d("LOG",  "null");
                DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
                        .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                        .document();
                String docId = documentReference.getId();

                Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                map1.put(Statics.CATEGORY_FIELD_IN_FIRESTORE, categoryReceive);
                map1.put(Statics.CATEGORY_ID_FIRESTORE, docId);

                documentReference.set(map1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Statics.COLLECTION_NAME)
                                    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                    .document(docId)
                                    .collection(Statics.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                    .document();
                            String id = documentReference.getId();

                            Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                            map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_ID_FIRESTORE, productId);
                            map1.put(Statics.PRODUCT_DOCUMENT_ID_FIRESTORE, id);

                            documentReference.set(map1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        startActivity(new Intent(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(AddProductSwipeCardsActivity.this, "Some problem occurs we add this product soon automatically", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: this method runs more than one time and it add data to fire  store more than one time

Comment: Most likely it's because you are getting the data in real-time. Have you tried to use [only a get() call](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)?

Comment: This function is run 1 time more than before it run

Comment: Good to hear that. You're very welcome.

Comment: @AlexMamo Do you want to write up an answer to the effect of "to get data only once, use `get`"?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey puf. Yep, I just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This method runs more than one time and it adds data to Firestore more than one time.

This is happening because you are using [Query#addSnapshotListener(EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) for getting the data in real-time. This means that each add/update/delete operation that takes place in the collection where the reference is pointing to, invokes the listener, hence that behavior.

To avoid this, you should simply use a [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()) call, for getting the data only once.

> Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.

For more info on how to get the data from Firestore using get(), please check the following article, where I have explained 4 different approaches:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)